Shoujo/josei manga about a girl's sister with a bad personality, but things always accidentally go her way
This manga has a very classic shoujo style but the sister with the bad personality has a similar style to Neighborhood Story by Ai Yazawa. She always had done-up curly hair and big lips.
Its not a modern manga; it's at least 10 years old, but I can't pinpoint the date.
Set in Japan, the story began from the POV of the normal sister who is a university student. It's about her sister who has a bad personality and things accidentally always go her way.
From this point, it focuses on the mean sister. She actively goes out to do 'one bad deed' everyday, but it always ends up in her favour.
Some points of the story were:

She wanted to marry someone for selfish reasons, but he falls for her anyway.
She called the pound on a neighbourhood dog because it was loud and annoying, but it actually attacked a local child, so she was known as a hero.
She got annoyed at the boss nagging her, so she reported him to HR and he got fired. She was a hero because he was harassing women in the workplace.

The story always focuses on her 'selfish' or 'bad' personality but it always comically goes her way in the end.

Does this contain any sci-fi or fantasy elements?

It seems off-topic, but if the concept of "misundertood villain" appeals to you, check out  "evil lord of an intergalactic empire". It actually IS sci-fi/fantasy, but shounen instead of shoujo, action instead of whatever this is.
